# i have a custom table and i want to display images from json but it displays same image in all rows

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, uiimageview, tablecell

```
 // delegate method that returns json   
-(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{
    if (retrievedData.count > 0)
    {
        userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];

        for (userObj in retrievedData)
        {
        NSLog(@"%@is the value",retrievedData);

        url_Img1=@"http://kiascenehai.pk/assets/uploads/event-images/50x50-thumb/";
        url_Img2=userObj.event_dpURL;
        url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];

        NSLog(@"Show url_Img_FULL: %@",url_Img_FULL);
            [tableData addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];
            [table reloadData];
        }

    }
}
//to display data in table:::
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]]];
```

Comment: put it in your for loop [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]]];

Comment: actually u r calling the url_Img_FULL directly, it showing the last image only

Comment: add url_Img_FULL in to one nsmutablearray

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more details about the problem you are facing. Copy-pasting your code won't help. `userObj` is used in two scopes, and it cannot be determined which `userObj` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create one `NSMutableArray` globally in interface section and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` method

```
NSMutableArray *arr;
```

After that add `url_Img_FULL` inside `arr`

```
[arr addObject:url_Img_FULL];
```

Change this line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]]];
```

to

```
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];
```

Also in `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath` return arr.count.

Comment: yogesh its not working properly. the app goes to crash if json got long response.Have you some other idea

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[User length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa4ed500'

Comment: @user3807662 It is not related with the tableview, it is related with something else, where you can't use `length` for object `User`.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException

Comment: [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];                                 and here it shows :Thread 1 sigbrit

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arr.count;
}
and by coding this except of  tabledata.count ; it do not show aven a single image

Comment: fixed it .Thanks Yogesh again

Answer (score 0):

```
Use GCD to download some thing like this

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

       //write the code to download image


         }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Capture the indexPath variable, not the cell variable, and use that


            [tableview reloadData];

        });
    });

and cellforrowatindexpath write

if(are.count>0)
{
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];
}

return cell;
```